# In Django, how do I check if a user is in a certain group?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I created a custom group in Django's admin site.

In my code, I want to check if a user is in this group. How do I do that?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can access the groups simply through the `groups` attribute on `User`.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

group = Group(name = "Editor")
group.save()                    # save this new group for this example
user = User.objects.get(pk = 1) # assuming, there is one initial user 
user.groups.add(group)          # user is now in the "Editor" group
```

then `user.groups.all()` returns `[<Group: Editor>]`.

Alternatively, and more directly, you can check if a a user is in a group by:

```py
if django_user.groups.filter(name = groupname).exists():

    ...
```

Note that `groupname` can *also* be the actual Django Group object.

Comment: The actual checking would be `if user.groups.filter(name=group_name).count(): # do something`

Comment: or use .exists() instead of .count()

Comment: The question is about query the User model for the groups it belongs, not how to instantiate'em... -.-

Answer (score 274):

Your **User** object is linked to the **Group** object through a **ManyToMany** relationship.

You can thereby apply the **filter** method to **user.groups**.

So, to check if a given User is in a certain group ("Member" for the example), just do this :

```
def is_member(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='Member').exists()
```

If you want to check if a given user belongs to more than one given groups, use the **__in** operator like so :

```
def is_in_multiple_groups(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name__in=['group1', 'group2']).exists()
```

Note that those functions can be used with the **@user_passes_test** decorator to manage access to your views :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test

@login_required
@user_passes_test(is_member) # or @user_passes_test(is_in_multiple_groups)
def myview(request):
    # Do your processing
```

For class based views, you might use `UserPassesTestMixin` with `test_func` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    def test_func(self):
        return is_member(self.request.user)
```

Hope this help

Comment: I'm not sure about the inner workings of django's DB access, but this seems a lot more efficient then some of the other suggestions, like getting all the users in a group and doing a standard python `user in groups` (or vice versa).

Comment: Don't you have to add `.exists()` to the end to return a boolean? Otherwise `is_member()` and `is_in_multiple_groups()` will return a `QuerySet`, which may not give the desired result.

Comment: According to Django's documentation, it is indeed faster to use exists() since it does not evaluate the queryset : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists

Comment: You probably want to have the superuser pass the test (without querying the database): `def is_member(user): return user.is_superuser or user.groups.filter(...`

Comment: `is_in_multiple_groups` can be more explicitly named `is_in_some_groups` since it does not require that user be a member of *all* the groups

Comment: how do you use this one in class based view??

Comment: What file do you put this `def` in? I tried models.py and admin.py but neither of those seems right.

Comment: It always returns **False** in 2022 / Django 4.0

Comment: @DavidRhoden You could make a page in your app called ***functions.py*** and add it there, then in ***views.py*** or whatever python file you gonna use it if it is in that app, you just import it from the top like this `from .functions import is_member `. If you import it from another app, then `from {thatAppName}.functions import is_member ` where {thatAppName} is the name of your app, for example if you named it app1, then `from app1.functions import is_member`

Comment: If this happens to someone else. It returned **False** because I had lowercase, the first letter is capital letter, and I had lowercase. I saw this when I went to admin and checked what group this user was in.

Comment: How do you add this to a **Class Based View**?

Comment: I edited my answer to add an example for class based views

Answer (score 20):

If you don't need the user instance on site (as I did), you can do it with

```
User.objects.filter(pk=userId, groups__name='Editor').exists()
```

This will produce only one request to the database and return a boolean.

Answer (score 17):

If you need the list of users that are in a group, you can do this instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="group name").user_set.all()
```

and then check

```
 if user in users_in_group:
     # do something
```

to check if the user is in the group.

---

**Update 2023**

Looking at this solution 10 years later, I'm pretty sure that I would NOT want to ever to fetch a whole list of users like this. It's something that would be problematic at scale.  You would only want to fetch a list of users in a very specific use case where there were assurances that the list of users was going to remain small, or if you were just using the Django shell.

Comment: This doesn't scale well for sites with more than a small number of users, since it will load large subsets users table into memory each time it runs.

Comment: `user.groups.filter(name="group name").exists()` should work fine. The solution you have written uses two queries and therefore not very optimal.

Comment: as it says, "if you need the list of users that are in a group"...

Comment: indeed, a good solution to reduce db queries in order to check a bulk of users relationship with a given group

Comment: Looking at this solution 10 years later, I'm pretty sure that I would NOT want to ever to fetch a whole list of users like this.  It's something that would break at scale -- you would only want to use in a very specific use case where there where assurances that the list of users was going to remain small.

Answer (score 12):

If a user belongs to a certain group or not, can be checked in django templates using:

`{% if group in request.user.groups.all %}` 
`"some action"`
`{% endif %}`

Comment: this not work for me, seems that require  compare group with groups name

Answer (score 10):

You just need one line:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test  

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='companyGroup').exists())
def you_view():
    return HttpResponse("Since you're logged in, you can see this text!")
```

Comment: Not very clean code though, and not very reusable, but +1 for getting it into one line.

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.name == 'GroupName' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have been looking for this. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have similar situation, I wanted to test if the user is in a certain group. So, I've created new file utils.py where I put all my small utilities that help me through entire application. There, I've have this definition:

```
utils.py

def is_company_admin(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='company_admin').exists()
```

so basically I am testing if the user is in the group **company_admin** and for clarity I've called this function **is_company_admin**.

When I want to check if the user is in the **company_admin** I just do this:

```
views.py

from .utils import *

if is_company_admin(request.user):
        data = Company.objects.all().filter(id=request.user.company.id)
```

Now, if you wish to test same in your template, you can add **is_user_admin** in your context, something like this:

```
views.py

return render(request, 'admin/users.html', {'data': data, 'is_company_admin': is_company_admin(request.user)})
```

Now you can evaluate you response in a template:

```
users.html

{% if is_company_admin %}
     ... do something ...
{% endif %}
```

Simple and clean solution, based on answers that can be found earlier in this thread, but done differently. Hope it will help someone.

Tested in Django 3.0.4.

Comment: In your `data = Company.objects.all().filter(id=request.user.company.id)`, what does Company signify? Is that your Model?

Comment: Yes @hayden, in this case Company is my model.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you wanna check user's group belongs to a predefined group list:

```
def is_allowed(user):
    allowed_group = set(['admin', 'lead', 'manager'])
    usr = User.objects.get(username=user)
    groups = [ x.name for x in usr.groups.all()]
    if allowed_group.intersection(set(groups)):
       return True
    return False
```

Comment: [FYI you can say { x.name for x in usr.groups.all() }](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
'Groupname' in user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

This evaluates to either `True` or `False`.

Comment: This is inefficient, since it'll fetch a lot more data, and then operate on it on django's side. It better to use `.exists()` to let the db do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it the following way. Seems inefficient but I had no other way in my mind:

```
@login_required
def list_track(request):

usergroup = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True).first()
if usergroup in 'appAdmin':
    tracks = QuestionTrack.objects.order_by('pk')
    return render(request, 'cmit/appadmin/list_track.html', {'tracks': tracks})

else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/cmit/loggedin')
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.objects.filter(username='tom', groups__name='admin').exists()`

That query will inform you user : "tom" whether belong to group "admin " or not

Comment: groups__name  with double underscore

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this. For group named `Editor`.

```
# views.py
def index(request):
    current_user_groups = request.user.groups.values_list("name", flat=True)
    context = {
        "is_editor": "Editor" in current_user_groups,
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

template

```
# index.html
{% if is_editor %}
  <h1>Editor tools</h1>
{% endif %}
```