# Check if object, obtained from collection of Base class, is object of subclass in Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Python and django newbie question, here is code:

```
class Client(User)
   #some fields

client=Client()
client.save()

user=User.objects.all()[0]

#want to ckeck type of user, expect that it is Client:
isinstance(user,Client) #returns false

#but this works:
isinstance(user,User) #returns true
```

But I expect that user is Client. What's wrong?

**Addition:**
Need to get subclass object first, and it works fine:

```
if hasattr(user,'client'):
        client=user.client
```

**Addition 2:** Guys, you so angry so I afraid to post anything more in this question :) It's closed, and I fully understood my absolutely vacuum in knowledge of django, python, polymorphism and other IT technologies, thanks ))

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  Django has a 'Group' model to allow you to distinguish different types of users.  Do not subclass Django's `User` class like this.  Read questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789021/in-django-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-certain-group.  That's the correct approach.  Delete all your code that attempts to subclass `User`.  Close this question.  And start again using `Group` correctly.

Comment: Why not to subclass User? Django allows it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance. I need to extend User with custom fields, so nothing is wring with subclassing.

Comment: But groups for distinguishing looks fine, I use that, thanks

Comment: "need to extend User with custom fields".  That's why there's a "Profile" extension to User.  Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users.  Do not subclass User.  And -- in general -- subclasses don't work the way you're describing them in the question.  If you think you need to use `isinstance`, you have failed to understand polymorphism.  For your need, just read the Django documentation on Groups and Profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Django's querysets aren't aware of inheritance. So when you query on User, it won't ever return the subclasses.

The easiest solution is to do something like this:

```
try:
    client = user.client
except Client.DoesNotExist:
    # handle exception
```

Of course, if you have multiple subclasses of User, this gets slightly more complicated. There are ways of getting Django to do model inheritance properly, but they're all a little bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

your expectation is wrong. you query the `User` class, why do you expect to get a `Client` out of it?!