# Check Django User Group

Tags: django

So I want to change what information is displayed based on the group the user is in.

So:

```
{% if user.is_staff %} 
......
```

That works but when I try and do

```
{% if user.is_China %}
```

This group doesn't work?

Is there a specific thing I need to do to find out if the user is part of a group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789021/in-django-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-certain-group

Comment: is_staff is inbuilt attr for django admin model User, is_china is not.
To able to use is_china you need a custom user model in which you can define is_china attr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you need is a custom template tag:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group 

register = template.Library() 

@register.filter(name='is_group') 
def is_group(user, group_name):
    group =  Group.objects.get(name=group_name) 
    return group in user.groups.all()
```

In your template:

```
{% if user|is_group:"group" %} 
    <p> User belongs to group </p>
{% else %}
    <p> User doesn't belong to group </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Where to define template tags?

Comment: Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1):

The only note to the Fazil Zaid answer is that a *Group.DoesNotExist* exception will be raised if no Group will be found by a group_name. In my opinion it would be better to handle this exception and return **False** if group does not exist.

```
@register.filter(name='is_group') 
def is_group(user, group_name):
    try:
        group =  Group.objects.get(name=group_name) 
        return group in user.groups.all() 
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist for more information about the exception.