# Restrict access to a part of a template to users that is part of a group using Class based views. Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-permissions

I want to restrict users in certain groups from accessing parts of the HTML template. I have a class based view that looks like this:

**Views.py**

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'main/mysite.html'
```

With function based views I can restrict access on a template based on someones group using `request.user.groups.filter(name='GROUP_NAME').exists()` from [In Django, how do I check if a user is in a certain group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789021/in-django-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-certain-group)

I tried changing my view.py and HTML template like this:

**views.py**

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'main/mysite.html'

    def dispatch(self, request):
        in_group =  request.user.groups.filter(name='GROUP_NAME').exists()
        return in_group
```

**HTML TEMPLATE**

```
....
{% if in_group %}
some code here shows up if user belong to group
{% endif %}
....
```

This will give me the correct display when the user is not a member of the group, but when they are a member of the correct group I get an attribution error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /mysite
Exception Value: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to get a context variable into your template when using a class-based view is to override the `get_context_data()` method:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'main/mysite.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['in_group'] =  self.request.user.groups.filter(name='GROUP_NAME').exists()
        return context
```

See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) for more on `get_context_data()`.