# how to check if a user is in a default django group? in the admin panel (admin.py)

Tags: python, django, admin, fieldset

My logic is that when a user with is_stuff privilege went to the admin panel and tried to create, for example, news, then the program checked him, in which group he is, if this group exists, then it should issue fieldsets with limited capabilities, or other fields...

I checked this link ([In Django, how do I check if a user is in a certain group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789021/in-django-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-certain-group)), but it does not work for my situation, since I have to check in the admin panel not return it to api or templates.

i tried to do the following: in admin.py
(a)

```
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
       group = Group(name="OutSource")
       if request.user.groups(name=group):
          # first_fields = {...}
       else:
          # second_fields = {...}
```

callback:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

admin.py (b):

```
if request.user.groups.all()[0].name == "OutSource":
```

callback:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

admin.py (c):

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name='OutSource').exists():
```

callback:

```
unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I found a solution to my question. Here is the answer if anyone needs it

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="OutSource").user_set.all()
    if request.user in users_in_group:
       # fields = (...)
    else:
       # fields = (...)
    return fields
```