# Django Many To Many Field Query Admin Page

Tags: python, django

I have a field in my student model called counselors. All I am trying to do is list the users that are in the group counselors to be displayed in this many to many relationship. How do i go about doing this? Here is the field in my model. Thanks

```
  counselor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Counselors', on_delete = models.PROTECT,null=True,blank = True)
```

The current setup only shows all the users within the User table not Users associated in the Counselors group.

Comment: I think this has been addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789021/in-django-how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-certain-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
counselor = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "Counselors"},on_delete = models.PROTECT,null=True,blank = True )
```